# Why does subsetting this data frame change its (formerly duplicated) column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, names

Consider

```
DF <- data.frame(
  x=1:5,
  y=5:1,
  z=rep(5,5),
  danger=11:15,
  danger=12:16,
  check.names = FALSE
)
drops <- c("x","z")
DF
DF[!(names(DF) %in% drops)]
```

With this, we get the following output:

```
> DF
  x y z danger danger
1 1 5 5     11     12
2 2 4 5     12     13
3 3 3 5     13     14
4 4 2 5     14     15
5 5 1 5     15     16

> DF[!(names(DF) %in% drops)]
  y danger danger.1
1 5     11       12
2 4     12       13
3 3     13       14
4 2     14       15
5 1     15       16
```

As we can see, the last column's name was changed. Why?

Comment: It is because in `data.frame`, it doesn't allow duplicate column names.  So, internally, it calls `make.names` and `make.names` calls `make.unique` i.e. `make.unique(rep("danger", 2))#[1] "danger"   "danger.1"`.  You are overriding that effect in `check.names = FALSE` which is by default `TRUE` and triggers the functions `make.unique`.  But, in the subsequent selection, it gets triggered because the default mode in data.frame doesn't support duplicates

Comment: @akrun And the use of `check.names=FALSE` doesn't do anything about that?

Comment: That is the reason it was overrided while constructing the data.frame.  But, it is not recommended to have duplicate column names in data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things happening in the code. The OP overrided the default checking of the column names with `check.names = FALSE` while constructing the data.frame, which allowed the duplicate column names because if it is TRUE, then the chain of events that gets triggered will be the following functions being called

```
 make.names -> make.unique
```

and `make.unique` by default appends a `.` with a number as suffix for the duplicate elements

```
make.unique(rep("danger", 2))
#[1] "danger"   "danger.1"
```

`duplicate` column names are not recommended in `data.frame`.  So, when we do the subset with `[`, a call to Extract method for data.frame is being made

```
methods(`[`)
```

return a bunch of methods and one of them is `[.data.frame` which does the check names and assign the `names` with unique names got from `make.unique`

```
`[.data.frame`
...
...
if (has.j && anyDuplicated(nm <- names(x))) 
        names(x) <- make.unique(nm)
...
```

With `[`, the arguments being passed are only the `i`, `j` and `drop` along with the object 'x'

```
formalArgs(`[.data.frame`)
#[1] "x"    "i"    "j"    "drop"
```

So, we cannot override that behavior by passing any `check.names` here

---

However, a `matrix` have no issue with having duplicate column names

```
as.matrix(DF)[, !(names(DF) %in% drops)]
#      y danger danger
#[1,] 5     11     12
#[2,] 4     12     13
#[3,] 3     13     14
#[4,] 2     14     15
#[5,] 1     15     16
```

NOTE: It is recommended not to have duplicate column names either in `matrix` or `data.frame` as this may create unnecessary bugs in the code